# Windows 10 blocks .exe

Tags: windows-10, blocking

I have a Windows 10 Pro machine (version 10.0.18362) and an executable file `test.exe` I created myself.

The executable runs fine from a `cmd` terminal on other Windows machines (including other Windows 10 Pro machines), but not on this one. There is no error, no output, nothing. A new prompt simply appears underneath in the `cmd` terminal, with nothing in between. This is the puzzling part.

**Why does Windows refuse to run the executable, or show any error? How can I "unblock" it and make it run?**

I tried Googling for this problem, and found suggestions such as (e.g. [here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/85418-disable-downloaded-files-being-blocked-windows.html) or [here](https://windowsreport.com/exe-files-not-opening-windows-10/)):

- disable Defender and firewall (didn't help)
- edit Group Policy Settings and run `cmd` as administrator (didn't help), or
- edit registry (didn't help)

Any other ideas?

---

`test.exe` was created by running `pyinstaller --onefile test.py` on the following (trivial) Python 3.7 program:

```
print("Success")
```

Again, the same executable works fine on other Windows machines.

There is no firewall, antivirus, defender or shield running. I am running the correct executable in the correct directory.

---

**EDIT**: just found another clue: The same executable works if run from a pen drive. It doesn't work when run from the C: drive.

What settings or process could possibly be causing this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100488/discussion-on-question-by-user124114-windows-10-blocks-exe).

Comment: "The same executable works if run from a pen drive" : Does the folder on the pen drive contain more software files than were copied to the disk?

Comment: did you run in from a cmd that was executed as administrator (when it's stored in `C:\`)? Is it actually in the root folder of the C-drive or in a subfolder?

Comment: Have you tried to check the Windows Event Logger if there is an error or warning that can help you to understand what's happening?

Comment: Run [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and see if it gives you any clues.

Comment: @Albin I ran it both as administrator and not; makes no difference.

Comment: @harrymc it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try adding `--win-private-assemblies` so that it won't try using newer libraries that may be on this particular system:

> Any Shared Assemblies bundled into the application will be changed
>   into Private Assemblies. This means the exact versions of these
>   assemblies will always be used, and any newer versions installed on
>   user machines at the system level will be ignored.

Also, make sure you're not actually running from the root of `C:\` or some other protected area.

Comment: Can you expand on that `make sure you're not actually running from the root of C:\ or some other protected area`? What's that?

Comment: Sorry for not referencing this, but I believe unelevated programs can't write files to `C:\ ` and other protected areas, like systems folders or even `Program Files`. They are allowed to create directories in `C:\`, however.

Comment: There's no writing going on, so that doesn't seem relevant.